# How do I slice a pandas dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

When I use the following code:

```
frioMurteira = data.loc[(data["POM"] == "Murteira" & data["TMP"] > 7.2), ["DTM","TMP"]]
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Could you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think there is an error with your braces, try this:

```
frioMurteira = data.loc[(data["POM"] == "Murteira") & (data["TMP"] > 7.2), ["DTM","TMP"]]
```